# Goでソケットファイル作成する際、nginxユーザかつパーミッション777で作成したい

Tags: go, nginx

**Goでソケットファイル作成したら、rootユーザかつパーミッション755で作成されました**

```
func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("unix", "/var/run/hoge/go-hoge.sock")
```

---

**Q1.ソケットファイルを、nginxユーザかつパーミッション777で作成するには？**
・下記を試しましたが、何も変わりませんでした

```
func main() {
　　syscall.Umask(0777)
    l, err := net.Listen("unix", "/var/run/hoge/go-hoge.sock")
```

---

**Q2.ブラウザ経由でのGoファイル実行ユーザ確認方法は？**
・Nginx経由でブラウザからGoページを表示させようとしているのですが、この時、goファイルの実行ユーザは誰になるのでしょうか？
・どうやって確認すれば良い？？